# How to remove newline from end and beginning of every list element [python]

Tags: python, list, split, newline, strip

I've got the following code:

```
from itemspecs import itemspecs
x = itemspecs.split('#@#')
res = []
for item in x:
    res.append(item.split('##'))
print(res)
```

This imports a string from another document. And gives me the following:

```
[['\n1\nWie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?\n',
  '\nA. Michiel de Ruyter\nB. Piet Heijn\nC. De zilvervloot is nooit door de Nederlanders
 onderschept\n', '\nB\n', '\nAntwoord B De Nederlandse vlootvoogd werd hierdoor bekend.\n'], 
['\n2\nIn welk land ligt Upernavik?\n', '\nA. Antartica\nB. Canada\nC. Rusland\nD. 
Groenland\nE. Amerika\n', '\nD\n', '\nAntwoord D Het is een dorp in Groenland met 1224 
inwoners.\n']]
```

But now I want to remove all the `\n` from every end and beginning of every element in this list. How can I do this?

Comment: your code is not likely to work with this import syntax "import itemspecs from itemspecs" which does not exist; the correct syntax is "from <module> import <method>"

Comment: @baptistemm oops, edited it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by stripping "\n" as follow

```
a = "\nhello\n"
stripped_a = a.strip("\n")
```

so, what you need to do is iterate through the list and then apply the strip on the string as shown below

```
res_1=[]
for i in res:
    tmp=[]
    for j in i:
        tmp.append(j.strip("\n"))
    res_1.append(tmp)
```

The above answer just removes \n from start and end. if you want to remove all the new lines in a string, just use `.replace('\n"," ")` as shown below

```
res_1=[]
for i in res:
    tmp=[]
    for j in i:
        tmp.append(j.replace("\n"))
    res_1.append(tmp)
```

Comment: OP example contains multiple consecutive or near-consecutive newlines per string.  `strip()` won't get them all.

Comment: yes, that's what I tried but then I get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @andrew_reece, please check the OP, its to remove only from start and end

Comment: from itemspecs import itemspecs
x = itemspecs.split('#@#')
res = []
for item in x:
    res.append(item.split('##'))
print(res)

for i in res:
    i.strip('\n')

Comment: you are trying to strip on list. i is a list here .so, just loop through i and then strip it

Comment: I think we're just reading it differently.  For example, `\n1\n` is at the start of one string.  I think OP wanted to remove both those `\n`, even though 1 is in-between.  But I agree with your point about my solution, it will remove interior newlines as well, which is wrong.

Comment: @andrew_reece, i agree. question is kind of ambiguous. But, based on his question, my answer is correct. But, based on logic, yours seems correct

Comment: @InAFlash so like this:|  for i in res:  for n in i:  n.strip('\n')  | but then how can i get the new result out of it?

Comment: @andrew_reece, you removed your answer,so, i edited my answer to include your logic too. Hope that's fine

Comment: Yep, sure thing!

Answer (score 1):

`strip()` is easiest method in this case, but if you want to do any advanced text processing in the future, it isn't bad idea to learn regular expressions:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

l = [['\n1\nWie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?\n',
'\nA. Michiel de Ruyter\nB. Piet Heijn\nC. De zilvervloot is nooit door de Nederlandersonderschept\n',
'\nB\n',
'\nAntwoord B De Nederlandse vlootvoogd werd hierdoor bekend.\n'],

['\n2\nIn welk land ligt Upernavik?\n',
'\nA. Antartica\nB. Canada\nC. Rusland\nD.Groenland\nE. Amerika\n',
'\nD\n', '\nAntwoord D Het is een dorp in Groenland met 1224inwoners.\n']]


l = [[re.sub(r'^([\s]*)|([\s]*)$', '', j)] for i in l for j in i]
pprint(l, width=120)
```

Output:

```
[['1\nWie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?'],
 ['A. Michiel de Ruyter\nB. Piet Heijn\nC. De zilvervloot is nooit door de Nederlandersonderschept'],
 ['B'],
 ['Antwoord B De Nederlandse vlootvoogd werd hierdoor bekend.'],
 ['2\nIn welk land ligt Upernavik?'],
 ['A. Antartica\nB. Canada\nC. Rusland\nD.Groenland\nE. Amerika'],
 ['D'],
 ['Antwoord D Het is een dorp in Groenland met 1224inwoners.']]
```

Comment: strip is the easiest and preferred method over a regex. and also replace over regex when it comes to easy things like just removing new lines. am i wrong?

Comment: @InAFlash In this case yes. But it isn't bad to know regular expressions - it's very strong tool, if you know it.